# passing sparse xreg to stlf in R causes optimisation error

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to forecast a time series, and regress on temperature. The residuals show a different behaviour at low and high temperatures so I want to use piecewise linear approach, so learn different coeffecients for temperatures above and below 35 degrees.
The data is in a dataframe `data$x, data$Season, data$Temp`.

```
#Create data frame
len<-365*3 + 1 +31 
x<-rnorm(len,mean=4000000,sd=100000)
Season<-c(rep(3,62),rep(4,91),rep(1,90),rep(2,92),rep(3,92),rep(4,91),rep(1,90),rep(2,92),rep(3,92),rep(4,91),rep(1,91),rep(2,92),rep(3,61))
Temp<-rnorm(len,mean=20,sd=5)
data<-data.frame(x,Season,Temp)
#Create model matrix 
season_dummy<-model.matrix(~as.factor(data$Season)+0)
Temp_max=pmax(0,data$Temp-35) # creates 0, or a difference
Temp_restore<-restore_temp_up(Temp_max,data$Temp,35) # restores difference to original value
Temp_season_matrix_max=Temp_restore * season_dummy

#Create time-series and forecast
data_ts<-ts(data$x[1:1000],freq=365,start=c(2009,182))
len_train<-length(data_ts)
xreg1<-Temp_season_matrix_max[1:len_train,]
newxreg1<-Temp_season_matrix_max[(len_train+1):(len_train+30),]     
 stlf(data_ts,method="arima",h=30,xreg=xreg1,newxreg=newxreg1,s.window="periodic")

 >   Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
      non-finite value supplied by optim



Error in auto.arima(x, xreg = xreg, seasonal = FALSE, ...) : 
  No suitable ARIMA model found
In addition: Warning message:
In auto.arima(x, xreg = xreg, seasonal = FALSE, ...) :
  Unable to calculate AIC offset
>
```

Other threads suggest changing method solver from CSS to ML, but I cant edit these parameters in stlf. The help file shows an optional parameter "forecastfunction" but there are no examples of real explanation how to use it.

Note - when I set the min temperature to say 20, instead of 35, this works ok - I am sure it is because the xreg matrix containing temperatures above 35 degress is sparse (most temperatures are below this value), but I am not sure how to get around this. 
(I have included code for restore_temp_up - possibly inefficient, but included here for question completion.)

```
restore_temp_up<-function(x,original,k){
  if(!is.vector(x))
    stop('x must be a vector')
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if(!is.na(x[i])){
      if (x[i] > 0){
        x[i]<-x[i]+k
      }
      if (original[i] == k){
        x[i]<-original[i]  ## this is the case if original WAS =k, then dont know whether original is 0, 
      }
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: I added code to add a dataset. I cant provide the data set I use at work (legal reasons, etc), but I simulated somthing. Basically, the temperature season model matrix has to be sparse, since most temperatures will be below 35 degrees, but I still want to be able to build a model for the days where temperatures are above this value.

Comment: restore_temp_up - I wrote this (possibly modified some code floating on the Internet). Otherwise pmax(0,data$Temp-35 gives a difference (e.g.5, if Temp=40). I guess as far as the regression is concerned, maybe restoring this back to 40 is unnecessary?

Comment: I know. Any suggestions on how to add dummy values to populate this matrix? (I have more values in the data set I am using, but still too few). Is there any way to do piecewise-linear under these circumstances? ie - only including values above 35 degrees?

Comment: I may have figured it out. If I replace the appropriate lines above with: `xreg1<-Temp_season_matrix_max[1:len_train,c(1,4)]`
`newxreg1<-Temp_season_matrix_max[(len_train+1):(len_train+30),c(1,4)]` this works ok in my data set. That is, most of the high temperatures appear in Summer and Spring (season columns 1, and 4) - hence there is no need to pass in the other columns as part of xreg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design matrix is rank deficient so the regression is singular. To see this:

```
> eigen(t(xreg1) %*% xreg1)$val
[1] 1321.223    0.000    0.000    0.000
```

You cannot fit a regression model with a rank deficient design matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I have several design matrices for different lags, so it is worth doing this check on each one for rank deficiency, before passing in to the function. This is due to some columns containing all zeros (due to zero-ing all values below a set temperature, e.g. 35.) Thanks Professor Hyndman.